# Fadeout Youtube Video on click event without mute music

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i Fadeout Youtube Video on click into video, without mute music background.?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div.ytp-scalable-icon-shrink").click(function() {
        jQuery("#auto_hide").delay(15000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: On which browser/device the sound is muted?

Comment: whenever the fadeout event will occur, the embedded video sound would be mute or not..?

Comment: But have you tested it or not...???

Comment: i am trying to trigger event on click of the pause button class. but nothing is happen. and also try to do that by taking the div outside the iframe by providing it id. but nothing i got.

Comment: It sounds like completly unrelevant to your question. So what is your issue???And you have to provide minimalistic sample in question to replicate your issue, if any...

Comment: i am trying to do this first time. as like jquery do. i was tried to do this onclick fadeout. but youtube iframe is not listen the jquery code that i add above. i am trying to know that how i can trigger event on click on the youtube iframe.??

Comment: can u help me to solve this issue..?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use fade out use `opacity` instead.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.ytp-scalable-icon-shrink").click(function() {
    jQuery("#auto_hide").delay(15000).aniamte({
      oapcity: "0"
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: the play class of youtube iframe not trigger on click event of jquery. i had alert simple alert on click. but nothing was displayed. any help..?

Comment: That appears to be separate from your question.